# mergesort vector c+ opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mergesort

I need to order a vector of the coordinates for points not present but to the value obtained by pointing the coordinate in a matrix. For example

```
vector < Point > // v has two coordinates within
Mat D ( 2,2 ) ;
int a = v [ 0 ] .x ;
int b = v [ 0 ] .y ;
int c = v [ 1 ] .x ;
int d = v [ 1 ] .y ;
if ( D.at < int > ( a, b) <  D.at<int> ( c, d ) )
// Sort in ascending order
```

I tried to use mergesort with the appropriate changes to search " the coordinate values ​​":

```
void work::merge(vector<cv::Point>& Q1, int low, int high, int mid, Mat & Densita)
{
    cout << "merge" << endl;
    int i, j, k;
    vector<cv::Point> c;
    i = low;
    k = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        cout << "-" << endl;
        int X = Q1[i].x;
        int Y = Q1[i].y;
        int W = Q1[j].x;
        int Q = Q1[j].y;
        int a = Densita.at<int>(X, Y);
        int b = Densita.at<int>(W,Q);
        if (a < b)
        {   
            cout << "min" << endl;
            c.push_back(cv::Point(X, Y));
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "max" << endl;
            c.push_back(cv::Point(W, Q));
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        cout << "D" << endl;
        int X = Q1[i].x;
        int Y = Q1[i].y;
        c.push_back(cv::Point(X, Y));
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= high)
    {
        cout << "§" << endl;
        int W = Q1[j].x;
        int Q = Q1[j].y;
        c.push_back(cv::Point(W, Q));
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for (k = low; k < high; k++)
    {
        cout << "***" << endl;
        Q1.at(k) = c.at(k);
    }

}


void work::mergesort(vector<cv::Point>& Q1, int low, int high, Mat & Densita)
{   
    cout << "RichiamoMergesort" << endl;
    int mid;
    if (low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        mergesort(Q1, low, mid, Densita);
        mergesort(Q1, mid + 1, high, Densita);
        merge(Q1, low, high, mid, Densita);
    }
}
```

but after entering the merge he works a bit and then returned me this error

```
invalid vector<T> subscript ------>with vs2015
```

why? what am I doing wrong? how to solve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should achieve this by providing a custom comparator to the `std::sort` function, not by rewriting it. Something along the lines of:

```
struct PointCmp {  
    Mat* d;
    PointCmp(Mat* _d): d(_d) {} 

    inline bool operator() (const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
        return d->at<int>(p1.x, p1.y) < d->at<int>(p2.x, p2.y);
    }
};

int main() {
   // other stuff
   std::vector<Point> v;    
   Mat d(2, 2);
   std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), PointCmp(&d));
}
```